# If condition for comparing a string in Expect script

Tags: shell, tcl, expect

I have a expect script where I want to check uname -a.

if the remote server is Linux then I will run few more remote command using expect. If it is Aix then I will run few other set of commands. However I am not able to create the if condition. Can any one please help me?

```
expect <<'EOF'
spawn ssh user_name@server "uname -a"
set count 0
expect {
"password:" {
send password\r
exp_continue
}
"Permission denied" {
    incr count
    exp_continue
  }
}
set strname LINUX

set results $expect_out(buffer)

if {$strname == $results}
{
puts $results
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `uname -a` command output will not just have the word `Linux` or `Aix`, but also the more info. So, it would be better to use `regexp` to check whether if it contains the word.

```
#!/bin/bash
expect <<'EOF'
spawn ssh dinesh@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx "uname -a"
set count 0
expect {
    timeout {puts "timeout happened"}
    eof {puts "eof received"}
    "password:" {send "password\r";exp_continue}
    "Permission denied" {incr count;exp_continue}
}

set results $expect_out(buffer)

if {[regexp -nocase "Linux" $results]} {
        puts "It is a Linux Machine"
} elseif {[regexp -nocase "Aix" $results]} {
        puts "It is a AIX machine"
} else {
        puts "Unknown machine"
}
EOF
```

Else, you should have used `uname` command alone which will only produce what is indeed needed to us. In that case, your given code will work fine.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` in the beginning is wrong.