# Expect checking for a string or no output at all

Tags: shell, tcl, expect

I'll preface this with my first time working with Expect, and I absolutely love it so far! How do you make except account for `timeout`, `eof`, and either an output message or no message at all?

I've got an expect script that is fired off from a bash script. The expect script is solely used to ssh into a server and perform a user deletion. If the deletion is unsuccessful, an error message of `$username does not exist` appears, followed by a new blank input line. However, if the action is successful, no message is returned and it immediately jumps to a new blank input line to perform the next action.

I found [a similar stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174807/if-condition-for-comparing-a-string-in-expect-script) on how to deal with possible outputs, though I'm having trouble implementing a solution where no output is returned. Here's a snippet of my best attempt so far:

```
send "userdel $userdel_username\r"

expect {
  timeout { send_user "timeout on deletion\n"; exit 1}
  eof { puts "received eof\n"; exit 1}
  -re "^.*(?=exist).*\$" { set userdel_fail 1;} # easy way to check for the error
  -re "\$.*" { set userdel_fail 0;}
}

if {$userdel_fail == 1} {
    send_user "$userdel_username does not exist"
} else {
    send_user "$userdel_username deleted successfully"
}
```

This solution always hits the last line of the expect block since there will always be an input. I've tried leaving out the `-re "\$.*" { set userdel_fail 0;}` completely, but that leads to every successful deletion hitting the `timeout`. If I leave out the regex to check for the error and only expect the input, I'm finding `$expect_out(buffer)` is returning blank, which makes sense.

I guess I'm confused as to how to work around this to handle this specific case. I do not have access to change the error handling, otherwise I feel like I'd want to just have it return some sort of success message. Open to any tips on how to handle this situation or alternate approaches.

Comment: You need to think in terms of what will be written to your script when there's “no output”. How would a user determine that the program (that you're trying to automate) produced no output instead of just hanging? Sometimes, this can be by detecting a prompt or something like that…

Answer (score 0):

You can make the remote command generate some text on success allowing you to match that text in your `expect` script.

For example:

```
send "userdel $userdel_username && echo SUCCESS\r"
```